# Left -j off mingw32-make command for Qt4?

Tags: qt, blackberry, qt4, mingw, blackberry-playbook

I accidentally left off the [-j [jobs]](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html#Options-Summary) when compiling the [Qt4 **git://gitorious.org/qt/qt.git**](http://qt.gitorious.org/) repository from mingw32-make as per the [Building Qt4](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building-Qt5-for-Blackberry) documentation. Will this make any other difference beside the amount of time it takes to compile?

**My understanding of the command.**

- My understanding of the command is that it controls the amount of
  jobs being performed but if nothing is set after -j in [jobs] then it
  may be pointless to have.
- I could be wrong because I still don’t have a complete understanding
  of the configure.exe command syntax (*eg. configure.exe -opensource
  -confirm-license -release -xplatform unsupported/blackberry-armv7le-qcc -arch arm -nomake examples nomake
  demos -no-neon -opengl es2 -prefix c:\dev\qt4install*).

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. make -j, make -j<N>, make -j1, make all must have the same build results, otherwise that'd be a bug. (e.g. make install for qtbase often fails on OS X with -j<N> => bug).

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld per Tom Seddon advice it is not a bug just how it manages compile process order.  If it fully compiles ( which I don't know if it will, still going ) then maybe a bug if one process is intended to start before another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-j` with no argument lets make decide. From your link, from the section for ‘`-j [jobs]`’:

> With no argument, make runs as many recipes simultaneously as possible.

If the makefile is correctly written there should be no difference between running it with or without `-j`, though (as you note) running one job at a time could be slower.

Comment: I guess that could be important.  I am thinking it could because I am thinking of this example; I am supposed to compile a new configure.exe before I compile Qt.  There may be similar process needed for the final Qt compile being controlled by the `-j` command.  What do you think?

Comment: You compile configure.exe? You most probably just run it.

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld Special process for Qt Blackberry setup.